# C# - override configuration manually

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I am using C# .net

I need to load an external configuration file (web.config) and override the values of all sections and all elements (of each section) in current Configuration.

i.e, after the override, the state should be:

> ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = ...the app settings from the web.config read...

and so on for all the sections.

In code something like (or simpler code, if any).

```
string s = "c:\test\web.config";

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s);
foreach(ConfigurationSection section in config.sections) {
  // **** What to do here in order to do: ConfigurationManager.Override(section)
  // so, I can use, i.e, line code such as : string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] ?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, and I want to participate it.

Here is the code:

```
// For the file name:
string s = "c:\test\web.config";

// Now creating configuration:
Configuration roamingConfig =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s);

// configure the map
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap =
    new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

configFileMap.ExeConfigFileName = s;

// Now add new configuration, based on the configuration file map.
Configuration configFile = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var allKeys = configFile.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys;
foreach (var key in allKeys) {
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] = 
     configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].value;
}

configFile.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

What I did in brief is declaring the configuration twice (the second one is open with map exe configuration), saved the file to it's native executing path, and refresh configuration section `appSettings`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to first overwrite config file of application using `SaveAs` function. And then refresh all sections of configuration using `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` function.

Option 1: With help of `RefreshSection`

```
string s = "c:\test\web.config";

var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s);

//Overwrite config file of app
configFile.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

//Iterate through each sections 
foreach(ConfigurationSection section in configFile.Sections)
{
    //Refresh each section
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(section.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Option 2: Add an example to update `key-value` pair of `AppSettings` section with value read from config in different location.

```
string s = "c:\test\web.config";
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s);
//Get all keys
var allKeys = configFile.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys;
foreach (var key in allKeys)
{
    // Set value in ConfigurationManager
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"] = 
                               configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't realy work for me for unit-test, which I need to use the library's methods with its own configuration file. The project is unit-test (ms-unit), I get the error: file c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft visual studion\2019\Proffessional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\ir0w25of.tmp is denied. Where the current configuration file, I mean the value of: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile : c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft visual studion\2019\Proffessional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\testhost.x86.exe.Config.

Comment: Many keys (all the keys in the configuration file, which may vary).

Comment: @Eitan Okay. In that case using `SaveAs` may not be optimized option because it will trigger `RefreshSection` many times. Perhaps it will be better to update `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` in loop from `configFile` values.

Comment: How can I do that? I know that I load the right configuration xml file, but how I cannot resolve the value inside the section (even in debugger, I didn't succeed. In loop foreach ... if (section.name == "appSettings" then what ??).

Comment: @Eitan At minimum you have to use `Save` and `RefreshSection`. So with some trick you can avoid `SaveAs` and instead use `Save`. But entirely everything in memory is not very obvious.

Comment: @Eitan Added one example code to update `AppSettings` section from config at different location. Please check if it works.

Comment: configFile.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys,Length is zero.
My configurationFile look like:
<configuration> 
<configSections> ... </configSections> 
<appSettings> <add key="..." value ="" > ... </appSettings> ... Also when I do: var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s); it is open correctly (if I open, i.e. another file that not exist, it doesn't open).

Comment: Also, I found a partial solution in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.8

What the above link solve is that AllKeys now has value (for roaming config - I change and did ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(s); and for exeConfigFileName = s; instead of configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = 
    roamingConfig.FilePath, because the roamingConfig.FilePath as the value "test.config.config". What I need is that ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys will have my new values (now it is empty).

Comment: Thank you anywhere for efforts (I marked your answer useful, since you give me good clues how to solve the problem). The solution I found, with some efforts, is bellow.

Comment: @Eitan Glad to help you. Thanks you finally solve it and letting me know.